# How are the Firebase analytics events in_app_purchase and app_store_subscription_convert being fired?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am trying to verify that these events are triggering at the correct step in our funnel with the right parameters but there's little documentation on how to figure this out.

According to this documentation https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484 there should be a free_trial parameter on in_app_purchase but we're not receiving this property.

I've tried looking for the source code but according to this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2159#issuecomment-760500119), the analytics package is not open source.

Any insight into these two events or where to learn more about how they're fired would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find your answer? I'm running into the same issue.  I'm trying to fire these events manually from a web app.

Answer (score -1):

Information from [these docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069) gives good insight as to when the analytics events are fired.

You can additionally fire events manually, both built-in events or define your own custom parameters.

After instantiating analytics, you can call

`logEvent(‘event_to_log’, {content: “you wish to log”})`

place this wherever you need in your call stack and it will manually fire accordingly.

Additional information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web#web-version-9).